# STSADM: enumallwebs -includefeatures question

Tags: stsadm

I cant seem to find any documentation on what the -includefeatures parameter does. Obviously it returns features in the output of the stsadm command, but is it deployed or activated features?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes it doesn't seem to be documented very well. It appears that it only displays activated features, both visible in the UI and hidden in the UI.

Sample output:

```
<Features>
        <Feature Id="00bfea71-c796-4402-9f2f-0eb9a6e71b18" Count="1" DisplayName="WebPageLibrary" InstallPath="C:\Program Files\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\Web Server Extensions\14\Template\Features\WebPageLibrary" Status="Installed" />
        <Feature Id="00bfea71-5932-4f9c-ad71-1557e5751100" Count="1" DisplayName="IssuesList" InstallPath="C:\Program Files\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\Web Server Extensions\14\Template\Features\IssuesList" Status="Installed" />
        <Feature Id="94c94ca6-b32f-4da9-a9e3-1f3d343d7ecb" Count="1" DisplayName="PublishingWeb" InstallPath="C:\Program Files\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\Web Server Extensions\14\Template\Features\PublishingWeb" Status="Installed" />
        <Feature Id="00bfea71-4ea5-48d4-a4ad-305cf7030140" Count="1" DisplayName="WorkflowHistoryList" InstallPath="C:\Program Files\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\Web Server Extensions\14\Template\Features\WorkflowHistoryList" Status="Installed" />
        <Feature Id="00bfea71-f600-43f6-a895-40c0de7b0117" Count="1" DisplayName="NoCodeWorkflowLibrary" InstallPath="C:\Program Files\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\Web Server Extensions\14\Template\Features\NoCodeWorkflowLibrary" Status="Installed" />
        <Feature Id="00bfea71-eb8a-40b1-80c7-506be7590102" Count="1" DisplayName="SurveysList" InstallPath="C:\Program Files\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\Web Server Extensions\14\Template\Features\SurveysList" Status="Installed" />
        <Feature Id="00bfea71-3a1d-41d3-a0ee-651d11570120" Count="1" DisplayName="GridList" InstallPath="C:\Program Files\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\Web Server Extensions\14\Template\Features\GridList" Status="Installed" />
        <Feature Id="22a9ef51-737b-4ff2-9346-694633fe4416" Count="1" DisplayName="Publishing" InstallPath="C:\Program Files\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\Web Server Extensions\14\Template\Features\Publishing" Status="Installed" />
        <Feature Id="00bfea71-513d-4ca0-96c2-6a47775c0119" Count="1" DisplayName="GanttTasksList" InstallPath="C:\Program Files\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\Web Server Extensions\14\Template\Features\GanttTasksList" Status="Installed" />
        <Feature Id="00bfea71-2062-426c-90bf-714c59600103" Count="1" DisplayName="LinksList" InstallPath="C:\Program Files\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\Web Server Extensions\14\Template\Features\LinksList" Status="Installed" />
        <Feature Id="00bfea71-2d77-4a75-9fca-76516689e21a" Count="1" DisplayName="workflowProcessList" InstallPath="C:\Program Files\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\Web Server Extensions\14\Template\Features\workflowProcessList" Status="Installed" />
        <Feature Id="00bfea71-a83e-497e-9ba0-7a5c597d0107" Count="1" DisplayName="TasksList" InstallPath="C:\Program Files\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\Web Server Extensions\14\Template\Features\TasksList" Status="Installed" />
        <Feature Id="00bfea71-4ea5-48d4-a4ad-7ea5c011abe5" Count="1" DisplayName="TeamCollab" InstallPath="C:\Program Files\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\Web Server Extensions\14\Template\Features\TeamCollab" Status="Installed" />
        <Feature Id="00bfea71-d1ce-42de-9c63-a44004ce0104" Count="1" DisplayName="AnnouncementsList" InstallPath="C:\Program Files\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\Web Server Extensions\14\Template\Features\AnnouncementsList" Status="Installed" />
        <Feature Id="d250636f-0a26-4019-8425-a5232d592c01" Count="1" DisplayName="ObaSimpleSolution" InstallPath="C:\Program Files\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\Web Server Extensions\14\Template\Features\ObaSimpleSolution" Status="Installed" />
        <Feature Id="00bfea71-52d4-45b3-b544-b1c71b620109" Count="1" DisplayName="PictureLibrary" InstallPath="C:\Program Files\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\Web Server Extensions\14\Template\Features\PictureLibrary" Status="Installed" />
        <Feature Id="541f5f57-c847-4e16-b59a-b31e90e6f9ea" Count="1" DisplayName="NavigationProperties" InstallPath="C:\Program Files\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\Web Server Extensions\14\Template\Features\NavigationProperties" Status="Installed" />
        <Feature Id="00bfea71-7e6d-4186-9ba8-c047ac750105" Count="1" DisplayName="ContactsList" InstallPath="C:\Program Files\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\Web Server Extensions\14\Template\Features\ContactsList" Status="Installed" />
        <Feature Id="00bfea71-de22-43b2-a848-c05709900100" Count="1" DisplayName="CustomList" InstallPath="C:\Program Files\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\Web Server Extensions\14\Template\Features\CustomList" Status="Installed" />
        <Feature Id="00bfea71-e717-4e80-aa17-d0c71b360101" Count="1" DisplayName="DocumentLibrary" InstallPath="C:\Program Files\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\Web Server Extensions\14\Template\Features\DocumentLibrary" Status="Installed" />
        <Feature Id="00bfea71-6a49-43fa-b535-d15c05500108" Count="1" DisplayName="DiscussionsList" InstallPath="C:\Program Files\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\Web Server Extensions\14\Template\Features\DiscussionsList" Status="Installed" />
        <Feature Id="00bfea71-f381-423d-b9d1-da7a54c50110" Count="1" DisplayName="DataSourceLibrary" InstallPath="C:\Program Files\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\Web Server Extensions\14\Template\Features\DataSourceLibrary" Status="Installed" />
        <Feature Id="00bfea71-9549-43f8-b978-e47e54a10600" Count="1" DisplayName="ExternalList" InstallPath="C:\Program Files\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\Web Server Extensions\14\Template\Features\ExternalList" Status="Installed" />
        <Feature Id="00bfea71-ec85-4903-972d-ebe475780106" Count="1" DisplayName="EventsList" InstallPath="C:\Program Files\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\Web Server Extensions\14\Template\Features\EventsList" Status="Installed" />
        <Feature Id="00bfea71-1e1d-4562-b56a-f05371bb0115" Count="1" DisplayName="XmlFormLibrary" InstallPath="C:\Program Files\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\Web Server Extensions\14\Template\Features\XmlFormLibrary" Status="Installed" />
      </Features>
```

Comment: The only documentation I can find is a passing reference about changes made in the Octobet 2009 CU: http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/office/sharepointserver/bb735839. The enumallwebs operation page doesn't even list it as a parameter: http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd793606(v=office.12).aspx or http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd789634(v=office.12).aspx

Comment: I know. I could get the info to print, but I just wanted to make sure it displayed what I wanted. Again, thanks for the quick and informative reply.

Answer (score 0):

This method shows features, setupfiles  and eventrecievers that are currently installed on the site. This seems to be helpful if you are planing to migrate to 2010.

Check this post for example - http://sharing-the-experience.blogspot.com/2011/08/stsadm-o-enumallwebs-includefeature.html